# Convert JSON with slashes to Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a sample JSON for an API I am consuming and I would want to convert to Array.

```
{
"function":"BEEP.postPayment",
"payload":"{\"credentials\":{\"username\":\"api_user\",\"password\":\"!*****\"},\"packet\": [{\"MSISDN\":\"0473949\",\"amount\":\"5\",\"serviceID\":54,\"currencyCode\":\"RIA\",\"nar ration\":\"Pay dstv\",\"accountNumber\":\"5285990\",\"extraData\":\"\",\"datePaymentReceived\":\"2018-08 -22 11:46:22\",\"payerTransactionID\":\"SBC20180822114622\",\"customerNames\":\"Simon uyar\"}]}"
}
```

How do I convert this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index `payload` contains JSON:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$payload = json_decode($array['payload'], true);
```